# RedirectToAction in Ajax call blocks other calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, treeview

I am sending an ajax call to get a kendo treeview partial view, but this partial view is located in another controller named "CommonController" and it requires configdata for the kendo treeview partial which I send using TempData. The Action method in CommonController returns the kendo tree partial View.

Below is my code:

**Ajax Call to Controller**

```
$.ajax({
        url: deploymentDirSim + "/FormJS/FoldersAndFilesTreePartialView",
        type: "get",
        contentType: "'application/json; charset=utf-8'",
        success: function(sdata) {
            $("#ffTreeViewDiv").html(sdata);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

**Controller Method**

```
public ActionResult FoldersAndFilesTreePartialView()
{
        FoldersAndFilesTreeConfigData configdata = new FoldersAndFilesTreeConfigData
        {
            Name = "treeViewFolderFile",
            HtmlAttributes = "height:100%; overflow:hidden;",
            CheckBoxes = false,
            ShowCheckBoxOnFolder = false,
            OnDataBound = "onFolderExplorerItemDataBound",
            OnSelect = "onFolderExplorerTreeViewItemSelect",
            OnRequestEnd = "",
            OnCheckBoxCheck = "",
            OnExpand = "onFolderExplorerItemExpand",
            OnCollapse = "onFolderExplorerItemCollapse",
            ActionName = "PopulateFoldersAndFilesTree",
            ControllerName = "FormJS",
            AreaName = "MyArea"

        };

        TempData[configdata.Name] = configdata;

        return RedirectToAction("FoldersAndFileTreeView", "Common", new { area = "", tempDataKey = configdata.Name });
}
```

**CommonController Code**

```
    public ActionResult FoldersAndFileTreeView(string tempDataKey)
    {
        ViewBag.configData = TempData[tempDataKey];
        return PartialView();
    }
```

It's working fine but in some circumstances due to any reason (eg. Network delay) the  "FoldersAndFileTreeView" partial view returns with some delay. The problem is that until and unless the partial request is in progress all the remaining calls such as scripts, stylesheets and image files downloads are all stuck and their status goes to pending.

Below is the snapshot of the network trace:

[image]

And due to the above problem the UI become stuck for a while.

Kindly please suggest to me what am I doing wrong? I want these calls to run asynchronously and not to block other calls?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can add js and css files in your master layout instead of inner view

Comment: `RedirectToAction` redirects you to specific action. Note: its __redirection__

Comment: Why are your doing `RedirectToAction()` in the `FoldersAndFilesTreePartialView` (as opposed to returning the partial view from that method)?

Comment: My objective to create a shared partial view for folders and files tree view and i have to show this partial from different controllers (I am creating it like a control which can be reused in multiple places with their different settings).